# Trying to add multiple values one below the other in a webpage with selenium python

Tags: python

trying to add multiple values one below the other using python on a webpage
my code

```
a= [820,827,826,637,865]
element = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_MainCategoriserContent_Map1_SubgroupsAndProducts1_txtProductSearch").send_keys('{}'.format(a))
```

but while entering the above in the below input on a webpage I want to enter it one below the other like this with a leading 0

```
0820
0827
0826
0637
0865
```

the final entry should look like this in the webpage
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4VXO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```py
a= [820,827,826,637,865]
for each in a:
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_MainCategoriserContent_Map1_SubgroupsAndProducts1_txtProductSearch").send_keys('{}'.format("0"+str(each)))
```

Comment: thanks for the code but just one thing when I run the above code on the website it is like this 08200827082606370865, is it possible to get each one below the other?

Comment: Adding a space after tpn helped thank You!!!
for each in a:
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_MainCategoriserContent_Map1_SubgroupsAndProducts1_txtProductSearch").send_keys('{}'.format("0"+str(each)+" "))